# Setting UIWebView width & height

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I need adjust the height and width of UIWebView so that the whole text is displayed within the view and the user need not scroll to read the text.

Does anyone has any idea how to get it?

Answer (score 8):

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

See also: [UIWebView+SFHFStringMetrics](http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/UI/)

Comment: i am using UIWebView+SFHFStringMetrics but getting Size (0.00,0.00) can u guide me what mistake i am making ?

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

By calling the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method on the `UIWebView` you can execute JavaScript from your application in the `UIWebView`.

```
// get the height of your content
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('id_of_content_container').offsetHeight;"];

// get the width of your content
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('id_of_content_container').offsetHeight;"];
```

The above will return an NSString object with the width and height of whatever element you pass into the `getElementById` function. With that information you should be able to resize the UIWebView to accommodate your content. An example:

```
CGRect frame = webView.frame;
frame.size.width = 100;
webView.frame = frame;
```

You may also need to reset `scalesPageToFit` again to get the content to readjust to the new frame size.

Another option would be to detect `window.height` and `window.width` on the HTML side and use JavaScript to adjust the content to fit within the aspects of the UIWebView.

Comment: the idea is not to change the frame of UIWebView... Say, the width & height of UIWebView is set to 320 & 440 respectively... now the idea is to fit the html content displayed in that 320x440 view only.... any suggestions???

Comment: Like the answers have pointed out, I don't think you'll be able to do this on the application side. You'll need to write some JavaScript on the HTML side that determines the width/height of the window and compares it with the width/height of the content container and adjusts accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are no special provisions on `UIWebView` for resizing to fit the content. You could set the `scalesPageToFit` property to `YES` to scale the content down, or you could make the view large enough to fit most reasonably sized pages. I infer from your question that you're displaying content you're in control of. If not, I'm not sure there's an easy programmatic way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thaks a ton for the answer!!!

yeah, tried with scalesPageToFit property set to YES.... but it shrinks the content too much and is not readable...

Comment: Looks like the UIWebView+SFHFStringMetrics category suggested above may be useful. It invokes some Javascript on the rendered document to determine its dimensions.